# How can I know if the certificate for an Endpoint is valid for SSL connection?

Tags: java, jersey

I try to send a post request to a `REST server`.
The certificate has been loaded in the key store and it is valid, but i still get the exception `Unable to finde a valid certification path to request target`

Is the problem with the `certificate` or with the `endpoint`?

Comment: the problem may be either the certificate itself or the certificate chain. If you post the certificate in the question and if the endpoint is publicly reachable, I can try to find out the error

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. I found what the Problem was: another certificate was given in the vm parameters in eclipse, so the given certificate in the code couldn't be taken.